# How does this series diverge by limit comparison test?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

How does this series diverge by limit comparison test? $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{\frac{n+4}{n^4+4}}$$

I origionally tried using $\frac{1}{n^2}$ for the comparison, but I'm pretty sure it has to be $\frac{n}{n^2}$ to properly compare.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\frac{n+4}{n^4+4} \leq  \frac{n+4n}{n^4} \leq \frac{5}{n^3}$,

hence, $\sqrt{\frac{n+4}{n^4+4}} \leq \frac{\sqrt{5}}{n^{3/2}}$

so the series converges by comparison with convergent p-series $\sum \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$

Comment: Wont c be equal to 0 though once you take the limit? c must be greater than 0 to conclude the test with b sub n

Comment: @LukeD I don't get $c = 0$.  For example, if you use my argument above you get $c = \sqrt{5}$.

Comment: This can also be done with the limit comparison test, which is what the OP asked for.

Comment: Yeah im curious to see the limit comparison test. But regardless, thanks for the soln.

Answer (score 8):

For this sort of thing it is strongly advised to do a **rough calculation first**.  We have
$$\sqrt{\frac{n+4}{n^4+4}}\approx\sqrt{\frac{n}{n^4}}=\frac1{n^{3/2}}\ ,$$
which suggests comparing with
$$\sum\frac1{n^{3/2}}\ .$$
We have
$$\sqrt{\frac{n+4}{n^4+4}}\bigg/\frac1{n^{3/2}}=\sqrt{\frac{n^4+4n^3}{n^4+4}}
  =\sqrt{\frac{1+4n^{-1}}{1+4n^{-4}}}\to1\quad\hbox{as $n\to\infty$}\ .$$
Since this limit exists and is finite and not zero, and we know that
$$\sum\frac1{n^{3/2}}$$
converges, your series **converges** too.  (Doesn't diverge!!!)

Comment: So the answer our teacher gave us is wrong... thanks for the heads up.

Comment: If your teacher said the series diverges, yes, that's wrong.